# В плагине tinyMce есть кнопка добавления шаблона, хочу что бы при нажатии на нее выскакивало сообщение

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

В плагине **tinyMce** есть кнопка добавления шаблона, хочу что бы при нажатии на нее выскакивало сообщение. Мне нужен элемент с классом `.mce-i-template` и он есть:

```
console.dir($(".mce-i-template")[1]);
i.mce-ico.mce-i-template - объект кнопки
```

В коде получаю элемент и ставлю обработчик **click**, но `alert()` не срабатывает:

```
$($(".mce-i-template")[1]).click(function(){
  alert("кликнул!");
});
```

Comment: два варианта: 1. ты вызываешь `.click(...)` когда нужного элементу еще нет на странице, 2. это все находится внутри какого-нибудь iframe, и из основной странице к ним просто нет доступа

Comment: Именно, при нажатии на кнопку создается iframe,  мне нужно что бы template изменялся динамически, а иначе какой смысл использовать готовый html но без возможности изменить содержимое внутри тегов

Comment: смысл в том что редактор сам навешивает нужные обработчики. возможно он предоставляет какой-нибудь интерфейс дл связи